# i want to check that only if My first test with priority 1 is failed then My test case with priority 3 should run

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

currently for my this code i want to check that only if My first test with priority 1 is failed then My test case with priority 3 should run.. what should i do?

```
 // login in to BIO

 @Test (priority=1)
 public void Login() throws Exception{
  browser.findElement(By.name("name")).sendKeys("johnmartin11");
  browser.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("johnmartin1111");
  browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.signup-btn")).click();
  Thread.sleep(20000);
  try{
       Thread.sleep(20000);
       WebElement element = browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a/div[1]"));
       String trb = element.getText();
       Assert.assertEquals("Blood", trb);
       System.out.println("Login as Buyer successful");
         }

          catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println("Login failed as Buyer");
          }




     }
     // Company Account page here
     @Test (priority=2) 
     public void CompanyAccount() throws Exception{
         browser.findElement(Companyac).click();
         Thread.sleep(20000);
         try{

               WebElement element = browser.findElement(Companyac);
               String cac = element.getText();
               Assert.assertEquals("Company Account", cac);
               System.out.println("in Company Account page Successfully");
              }
              catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println("Company Account failed");
              }
     }

         // Create Stock link check
//      @Test (priority=3) 
//          public void membertopartner() throws Exception{
//          Thread.sleep(20000);
//               browser.findElement(memberlink).click();
//               browser.findElement(By.linkText("Partner")).click();
//               Thread.sleep(20000);
//       try{
//             WebElement element = browser.findElement (By.linkText("Manage Product Stocks"));
//             String stocklink = element.getText();
//             Assert.assertEquals("Manage Product Stocks", stocklink);
//             System.out.println("stock link found");
//            }
//            catch(Exception e){
//             System.out.println("Stock link failed");
//            }
//       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependsOnMethods annotation in second method, that way if first one passes then only execute second one. Now according to your requirement you want to execute second only if first fails, then you've to adjust your Assert in that way, so I changed Assert.assertEquals to Assert.assertNotEquals

```
 @Test (priority=1)
     public void Login() throws Exception{
      browser.findElement(By.name("name")).sendKeys("johnmartin11");
      browser.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("johnmartin1111");
      browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.signup-btn")).click();
      Thread.sleep(20000);
      try{
           Thread.sleep(20000);
           WebElement element = browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a/div[1]"));
           String trb = element.getText();
           Assert.assertNotEquals("Blood", trb);
           System.out.println("Login as Buyer successful");
             }

              catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println("Login failed as Buyer");
              }

         }
         // Company Account page here -- Now this method will be executed   only when Login is successful.
         @Test (dependsOnMethods = { "Login" })
         public void CompanyAccount() throws Exception{
             browser.findElement(Companyac).click();
             Thread.sleep(20000);
             try{
                   WebElement element = browser.findElement(Companyac);
                   String cac = element.getText();
                   Assert.assertEquals("Company Account", cac);
                   System.out.println("in Company Account page Successfully");
                  }
                  catch(Exception e){
                   System.out.println("Company Account failed");
                  }
         }
```